# odbc under osx 10.7

Tags: mysql, odbc

I'm trying to install an ODBC driver under MacOSX 10.7 (Lion) since the last few hours... But I can't get it to work. I need one for the RODBC package in R to work with a DB.
Under 10.6 everything worked fine :-\
The old drivers are installed, but when I test it with `/usr/bin/iodbctest` I get the following message:

```
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0607.1008

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): ?

DSN                              | Driver                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lugv                             | MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver                   

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): lugv
1: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture (0) SQLSTATE=00000
2: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded (0) SQLSTATE=IM003
```

When I download the newest MYSQL ODBC Connector, it doesn't compile anymore and also doesn't have a bin or lib folder as mentioned in the manual...

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks!